# azure - wrong git url

Tags: git, azure

I'm new at azure so I have been following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python

I would like to use git but seems imposible because of the username field.

This is the format of git url:

> https://username@app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/app_name.git

Where my username is: ricardo.ccc@mydomain.com

Then the result of the url is according the tutorial is the following invalid url: Note the I have two '@'.

> https://ricardo.ccc@mydomain.com@mydemoapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/mydemoapp.git

According to my dashboard web

> https://ricardo.ccc@mydomain.com@mydemoapp.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mydemoapp.git

Which is still an invalid url.

Ofc I've tried removing my domain without luck:

> https://ricardo.ccc@mydemoapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/mydemoapp.git
>   https://ricardo.ccc@mydemoapp.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mydemoapp.git

Comment: Have you tried making a username such as `ricardo` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python#create-a-deployment-user ?

Comment: I’d recommend using ssh instead of https.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that's the next step, but I think i should i solve this first.

Comment: How so? Using ssh would make this issue redundant.

Comment: Use `https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net` as your git remote. The username is optional. You'll get prompted for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As evilSnobu suggest I can ignore the username in the url.

```
https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where my username is: ricardo.ccc@mydomain.com

It seems that when you create a deployment user with **Azure CLI**, it only **requires the user name must be unique within Azure**.

So, I guess that you could create a username like ricardo.ccc@mydomain.com.
As I have tested, when I visit the url, it looks like resolve all `test.com@joeymvcweb.scm.azurewebsites.net` as a host which is after the first @ symbol.

[image]

However, when I try to add your username on **Azure portal**, it prompts me that the **format is incorrect**. The complete information are as below:

> The user name can contain only letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores. The user name must start with a letter.

So, I suggest that you could recreate your deployment user with correct naming convention.

Comment: But there is a thing that i don't understand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/user?view=azure-cli-latest According to this I have setup a username where I understood i had to use my credentials azure account. If i setup any random user name how can I link it with my premium account?

Comment: Before you setup the above code, you need to login in an account, which can be link your random username with your premium account.